# How to combine the same words in sets into one word

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, dataset

Make the function unique (one, two) that can count the number of unique words that exist in sentences1 and sentences2 at once. The function has a special ability to combine all the same words into one word

```
def unique (one, two):

    result= unique('I like food', 'I like cat')
    print(len(result))
    print(sorted(result))
```

**Ouput**

```
4
['food', 'cat', 'likelike', 'II']
```

Comment: Hi! What's your question?

Comment: Please provide the code of `unique` function

Comment: I think the question is how to write the unique function.

Comment: I want to make the same word one, as if there are 2 words in the set of cat ('cat', 'cat'), then the result is ['catcat']

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is difficult to understand

Comment: @YeniEldima You want to have `('cat','cat')` if `cat` exists twice or do you just want to have one `cat` in the end result?

Comment: yeah, thanks for help

Comment: @CodePope he wants to concatenate the two `cat`s together and get `catcat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def unique (one, two):
    uniques = defaultdict(int)
    for word in one.split():
        uniques[word] = uniques[word] + 1
    for word in two.split():
        uniques[word] = uniques[word] + 1
    list_of_words = [word * count for word, count in uniques.items()]
    return list_of_words

result= unique('I like food', 'I like cat')
print(len(result))
print(sorted(result))
```

And the output:

```
4
['II', 'cat', 'food', 'likelike']
```

Comment: I don't think this produces the output as provided in the question.

Comment: I think the user wants the code to implement the `unique` function

Answer (score 3):

```
def unique(one, two):
    words = {}
    sentence = one.split() + two.split()
    for word in sentence:
        if word in words.keys():
            words[word] += word
        else:
            words[word] = word

    return [word for word in words.values()]

print(unique("I like food", "I like cat"))
```

will print `['food', 'cat', 'likelike', 'II']`

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
from collections import defaultdict

def unique(s1, s2):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for word in s1.split(' '):
        d[word].append(word)
    for word in s2.split(' '):
        d[word].append(word)
    return [''.join(word) for _, word in d.items()]
```